# nHibernate Criteria Query OR or IN?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, icriteria

I need to recreate a query using nHibernate Criteria.  This query had a where clause that was pretty ugly.

```
((t.Disposition_CD)='ac' Or    
 (t.Disposition_CD)='cc' Or  
 (t.Disposition_CD)='Co' Or  
 (t.Disposition_CD)='SF' Or  
 (t.Disposition_CD)='SC' Or  
 (t.Disposition_CD)='OR' Or  
 (t.Disposition_CD)='SV' Or  
 (t.Disposition_CD)='RI' Or  
 (t.Disposition_CD)='WN' Or  
 (t.Disposition_CD)='NC' Or  
 (t.Disposition_CD)='DN' Or  
 (t.Disposition_CD)='WT' Or  
 (t.Disposition_CD)='MA' Or  
 (t.Disposition_CD)='TO' Or  
 (t.Disposition_CD)='OC'))
```

so, I started here

```
IList leadList = 
     session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Lead)).Add(Expression.In("CallDisposition", 
     new string[] {"AC","CC" })).List();
```

the problem the Property on Lead is a `CallDisposition` Object and gives me a `Unknown entity class: System.String` error when I try to do this.  An Array of `CallDisposition` is what it's looking for.

Basically what I'm looking for is a list of Leads that meet all the or criteria of the original query.  Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: Using the code formatting button is a lot easier than 1000s of spaces...

Comment: Thanks Greg, your suggestion was very constructive and helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the properties of your entities it is hard to comment.

If the CallDisposition property is a CallDisposition entity that has a CallDispostionCode property then you could do something like this:

```
IList leadList = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Lead))
   .Add(Expression.In("CallDisposition.CallDispostionCode", 
                      new string[] {"AC","CC" })).List();
```

Or if CallDisposition has an Id you could modify your second solution to something like this:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<CallDisposition>()
    .Add(Expression.In("CallDispostionCode", new string[] { "AC", "CC" })
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("CallDisposition.Id"));

IList leadList = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(EmcLead))
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("CallDisposition.Id", criteria)).List();
```

This would be only one database hit using a subselect.

Comment: your second approach was just what I was looking for....one shot to the DB.  This monster is slow enough. :)

Answer (score 1):

ok...I achieved the desired results but I went about it a different way.

first I did this

```
IList DispList = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(CallDisposition)).Add(Expression.In("CallDispostionCode", new string[] { "AC", "CC" })).List();
```

followed by this

```
IList leadList = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(EmcLead)).Add(Expression.In("CallDisposition", DispList)).List();
```

if I stored the `CallDispositionCode` in the `Lead` object I would be able to right to the Lead and get the `CallDispositionCode`.  It's a design issue.

If anyone has any suggestions, or comments, I would be interested in hearing.